# TypeScript React Google Maps: 'google' does not exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I have loaded the google maps Javascript API in the `public/index.html` and in dev tools console I can log `window.google.maps` just fine.

[image]

But TypeScript doesn't know its there and I get this error `Property 'google' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)` How do I tell typescript it does exist?

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

function Map() {
    const mapRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const google = window.google;
//                          ^ Error: Property 'google' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'
    const myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(mapRef.current, mapOptions);
  return (<div ref={mapRef}></div>);
}

export { Map };
```

Comment: `declare const google`

Comment: Hey Bill, I have the same problem, could you please tell me how did you resolve the problem? I've tried the solution from @ritaj but it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: it's still unresolved but I plan to look at `google-map-react` t see how they did it

Comment: What does your line in `index.html` look like for loading the script? FWIW, for Google Maps and basic React, if you're using node, try installing the typings from Definitely Typed: `npm install --save[-dev] @types/googlemaps`. Those helped me a lot in doing the actual typings.

Answer (score 4):

google recommends to have ts.config.json with this setting.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["google.maps"]
  }
}
```

in the root of your project you have to create ts.config.json and add that property single property. this is how you create ts.config.json:

```
   npx tsc --init
```

Comment: This answer is what tipped me off the most to solving this issue for myself. According to Google's Map docs it says to install using `npm i -D @types/google.maps`

I took @Yilmaz 's suggestion of adding a "types" property to my tsconfig file, but instead of `googlemaps` I used `google.maps`.. and suddenly my Typescript is picking up all of Google Maps' typings from DefinitelyTyped.

Comment: @EarlePoole i think I made a typo :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

I thought about this some more. If you have not installed the Google Map typings from DefinitelyTyped, I suggest doing so:

`npm install --save @types/googlemaps`. (Or `--save-dev` if you only want them for your own development.)

Comment: I think you mean `'npm' not 'nom'

Comment: Corrected. Thank you. Autocorrect often does more damage than good, but my mistake in not catching the error.